# ASP.Net session (SQL Server) times out after 10 minutes regardless of what's stated in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I have an ASP.net website and a session with SQLServer session state mode. I've stated in the web.config that the timeout should be an hour, but it would timeout in exactly 10 minutes.

```
  <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer"      
  sqlConnectionString="objConnState"
  timeout="60"/>
```

I can see the session entry in the table:
[image]
Readable:
[image]

Something worth mentioning is, that the entire thing is an hour behind (I figured because it uses getutcdate() in the procedures and the defaults, and getutcdate() is an hour behind my time, no idea if that is relevant or not.

Is it possible a timeout is defaulted somewhere in the IIS or anywhere between the site, the server and the sql that overwrites my web.config setting?

The ASPState table is supposedly set correctly using the wizard.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <some irrelivant app keys
        .
        .
        .
        >
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="objConnRemote" connectionString="..."
        <add name="objConnLocal" connectionString="..."
        <add name="objConnState" connectionString=".."
        <add name="objConnTest" connectionString="..."
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer"      
      sqlConnectionString="objConnState"
      timeout="60"/>

        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, />
                <add assembly="System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, /></assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <machineKey decryptionKey="somekey,IsolateApps" validationKey="someotherkey,IsolateApps"/>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
            </controls>
        </pages></system.web>
    <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <!--was the reason for the java pop up alert on the  auto fill -->
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
    <system.webServer>

        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
            <files>
                <clear/>
                <!-- removes the existing default document list -->
                <add value="index.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

edit:
I just found out something quite strange. It doesn't magically set the timeout to 10 minutes as i tough initially. Instead it would kick me at equal intervals on every 10 minutes - 6 times an hour. Doesn't matter if i login at 15:01 or 15:09, or If I'm active OR not it would clear the variables and send me back to /login/ at 15:10 Every time for every login...

**AAAND final EDIT:**
Thank you all for taking part in this discussion. It turned out that my sys admin (the guy above me) had a script that runs every 10 minutes that checks if a user should be "kicked" to save resources. Appearantly the script doesn't take into account the new tables and database and clears it as well when it shouldn't. Hopefully when we stop/alter the script it should work, so far it works.

Comment: Are you using authentication that might cause the timeout?

Comment: the iis app pool has its own timeout, which is 20 mins by default. Did you alter this as well?

Comment: No I'm not using any authentication that might do that.

@rdans do you mean the app_pool idle timeout ?

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the web.config with the sensitive data obfuscated? This might help identify any other config setting that can cause the timeout. Have a look at this, albeit older, post from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TroubleshootingExpiredASPNETSessionStateAndYourOptions.aspx

Comment: @ИвоНедев yes that's what I mean. It may be irrelevant because you are saving sessions in the database, but for in memory sessions, this would end the sessions

Comment: @rdans I believe it's irrelevant to my case. Anyway it was 0 now it's 60 still times me out in 10 minutes.

Comment: @Chris, sorry Chris just now noticed your comment, web.config above.

Comment: Is this happening in development or production? It could be that the machine.config has different settings, especially in a hosted environment. Can you check in there and did you go through Scott's post?

Comment: Just for "fun" - but have you tried a lower timeout than 10 minutes to see if it even reacts to your config setting?

Comment: Checked the post, from what i can tell from the sql tables, it's successfully resetting it, on every refresh, the values in "Expires" field in the table refreshes by the amount that is in timeout.

I tried setting the timeout to 6 minutes, then 2 (in web.config), It still kicks me in exactly 10 minutes

Comment: Did you check for other *.config files that might override or transform your connection strings?  (I have been burned by that trick before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has a setting for the default connection timeout.  Open SSMS, connect to your server, (in the Object Explorer tree) right-click your server, Properties.  Under the page "Advanced", under the section "Network", look at the setting "Remote Login Timeout".  The default is 10 (minutes).  Try a different value like 30 or 60.

Warning: This sets the default timeout for ALL OF YOUR USERS.  When you increase this setting, your server will hold onto connections longer (using more RAM).  So, if this server is shared by more-than just your web server, you may want to research how to "scale out" the database for your app.

Comment: Currently It's 20 thanks anyway. BUT I just found out something even stranger, I'll try to explain in my post above + found the problem

Comment: Oh, based on your post above, your sys-admin might want to change that 20, back to a 10 and let SQL server manage the connections instead of making ninja scripts to do it.

Comment: I am confused all around here. the "Remote Login Timeout" states that it is the number of seconds to wait before returning from a failed remote login attempt. 

Do you mean Server Properties > Connections > Remote query timeout? (note this is also in seconds)

Comment: Good point @PaulBinder. After re-reading all of the edits, I can see that my answer is unlikely to help with session timeouts.  It only would help with long-running DB queries (which is what I thought the original problem was).  Your suggestion would be more accurate than mine.